# Appending List Elements to Another List (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements

I've made some code that has a list of new users and current users and checks to see if the username is available. If unavailable, it outputs a message saying so, otherwise outputs a message saying it's available. After this, I'm trying to append the elements of the new_users list to the current_users, on the condition that it doesn't already exist there. I would then like to print the current_users list to indicate the changes have occurred.

Here is my code so far - it only prints the current_users list without the changes still which is where my problem is.

```
current_users = ['alice', 'bob', 'mary', 'OSCAR', 'Simon']
new_users = ['jack', 'daniel', 'sue', 'mary', 'chris']

current_users_lower = [user.lower() for user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f"{new_user} unavailable\n")
    else:
        print(f'{new_user} available')

if new_user not in current_users_lower:
    current_users_lower.append(new_user)
print(current_users_lower)
```

Thank you for any help in advance. I know question formatting is really important here so i've tried my best to ask it as clearly as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you to the user who edited my code - I thought copying the code directly from my IDE it would carry the format into the post. Didn't realise it needed more work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, my advice would be to add the append as part of the `for` loop, while also using `current_users_lower` instead of `current_users`. All in all it would end up like this:

```
current_users = ['alice', 'bob', 'mary', 'OSCAR', 'Simon']
new_users = ['jack', 'daniel', 'sue', 'mary', 'chris']

current_users_lower = [user.lower() for user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users_lower:
        print(f"{new_user} unavailable\n")
    else:
        print(f'{new_user} available')
        print("Appending new user to list")
        current_users_lower.append(new_user)

print(current_users_lower)
```

Comment: you should also change `new_user` to lower

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and also assisting with my question formatting. Thanks a heap!!!

Comment: Cheers @slowlearner02 do come back if you have any other question, we're happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You were simply missing an indent.

```
current_users = ['alice', 'bob', 'mary', 'OSCAR', 'Simon']
new_users = ['jack', 'daniel', 'sue', 'mary', 'chris']

current_users_lower = [user.lower() for user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f"{new_user} unavailable")
    else:
        print(f'{new_user} available')
    if new_user not in current_users_lower:
        current_users_lower.append(new_user)
print(current_users_lower)
```

Comment: The if statement was not indented

Comment: Can't believe it was as simple as an indentation error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are only appending the last item of you new_users list to current_users_lower.  Try adding the if statement that appends the list to your for loop.

```
current_users = ['alice', 'bob', 'mary', 'OSCAR', 'Simon']
new_users = ['jack', 'daniel', 'sue', 'mary', 'chris']

current_users_lower = [user.lower() for user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f"{new_user} unavailable\n")
    else:
        print(f'{new_user} available')

    if new_user not in current_users_lower:
        current_users_lower.append(new_user)

print(current_users_lower)
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a positive and quick response from everyone here. Not sure why I felt so intimidated to post this now haha

Answer (score 0):

It's because the statement was not in the for statement.

```
 current_users = ['alice', 'bob', 'mary', 'OSCAR', 'Simon']
new_users = ['jack', 'daniel', 'sue', 'mary', 'chris']

current_users_lower = [user.lower() for user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f"{new_user} unavailable\n")
    else:
        print(f'{new_user} available')
        current_users_lower.append(new_user)
print(current_users_lower)
```

Answer (score 0):

use set operation. it makes code simple.

```py
current_users = ['alice', 'bob', 'mary', 'OSCAR', 'Simon']
new_users = ['jack', 'daniel', 'sue', 'mary', 'chris']

current_users_lower = set([user.lower() for user in current_users])
new_users = set([user.lower() for user in new_users])

print(f'{new_users.intersection(current_users_lower)} are unavailable')
really_new = new_users.difference(current_users_lower)
print(f'{really_new} are available')

print(current_users_lower.union(new_users))
```